# Importing a component class with another name

Tags: angular, import, rename

For **example**, I have a class with static functions having the name:

`SennenGoroshiNoJutsuComponent`

I want to import this class into another component and have to use its properties a decent amount of time. So i wanted to rename it as `sg`. Do we have something of the sort of

```
import { SennenGoroshiNoJutsuComponent } as sg from '../sennen-goroshi-no-jutsu.component';
```

with which I could import it?

Comment: may be `import * as sg from '../sennen-goroshi-no-jutsu.component';`

Comment: That imports the file. that means instead of the class being renamed sg, it will be a property of sg, which will make the syntax even longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import { SennenGoroshiNoJutsuComponent as sg } from '../sennen-goroshi-no-jutsu.component';
```

Have a look at [**Modules (Imports section)**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) for more info.